# Spring data find by id in with order

Tags: spring, mongodb, performance, mongorepository

I need to find a documents by spring data from mongo collection with the same ids as in id's list:

```
List<Task> findByIdIn(List<UUID> taskIds);
```

And it works, but tasks in response has not the same order as in taskIds list. But I really need the same order. The only solution that I found is the cycle for each task and execute fintById in every iteration. But I think one call findByIdIn() is faster then 5 findById calls. Could you help me, how can I guarantee order in this case?

Answer (score 0):

you can give a Sort instance to the mathod:

```
Set<Task> findByIdIn(List<UUID> taskIds, new Sort("fieldToOrderBy"));
```

Comment: what field do I need to set to "fieldToOrderBy"? I just need a same order as in taskIds. I don't need to arifmetical order UUID's in response.

Comment: What defines the order in taskIds? A date, the id itself?

Comment: No, it just an order for task executing. I have a task ids in order that tasks need to be executed, and this query need for select tasks by this ids.